# SQL/SQL-LITE - Counting records after filtering

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a table of customers and a table of sales order with the following schemas:

1. Customer = {id, name}
2. Sales_order = {id, customer_id, sales_representer}

With the following defintions :

1. id is a primary key in both tables.
2. customer_id is a foriegn key references customer.

I want to implement the following query :

```
For any customer whose sales_representer is 100, find the customer id, 
customer name and the number of his overall orders.
```

I built the following query:

```
select C.id, C.name, count(C.id)
from customer C, sales_order S
where   C.id = S.customer_id and 
        S.sales_represntor = '100'
group by C.id, C.nname;
```

But as a result of count(C.id) I get only the number of sales whose the sales_representer is 100. 
I know I can add another instance of sales_order (i.e. S2) and count from it but It seems to me not efficent at all.

Do anyone have a solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery to calculate the sales number.
(In SQLite, subqueries are often as efficient as a join.)

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM sales_order
        WHERE customer_id = customer.id) AS orders
FROM customer
WHERE id IN (SELECT customer_id
             FROM sales_order
             WHERE sales_representer = '100')
```

If you care about efficiency, you should check the queries with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html), or even better, just measure them.

Comment: Is the following solution is good too?                          select C.id, C.name, count(TS.cust_id)
from customer C, sales_order S, sales_order TS
where  C.id = S.cust_id and 
  C.id = TS.cust_id and
  S.sales_rep = '100'
group by C.id, C.name;

Comment: I hope you can understand something in what written above.. I just don't know how to do a new line in the comment box.

Comment: The additional join will result in a wrong number of (counted) records.

Comment: Can you please explain me why? I'm getting the same results as using the query you stated above. What could go wrong? Notice the statement "C.id = TS.cust_id" - I still use natrual join and not a simple cartezian multiplication.

Comment: The natural join is only between `customer` and the two `sales_order` instances; you still get a cartesian product between `S` and `TS`: [example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fd52f/4)

Comment: Thanks! You've really helped me with this example. The strange thing is that in my database the count column was identical using both queries. I will make sure how it is possible as I come back home.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `having` clause to demand that at least one sale was by representative 100:

```
select  C.id
,       C.name
,       count(*) as TotalSaleCount
from    customer C
join    sales_order S
on      C.id = S.customer_id
group by 
        C.id
,       C.name
having  count(case when S.sales_representor = '100' then 1 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to solve this with conditional aggregation:

```
select C.id, C.name, count(*) as Total_Orders,
       sum(case when S.sales_representor = '100' then 1 else 0 end) as SR100_Orders
from customer C join
     sales_order S
     on  C.id = S.customer_id
group by C.id, C.nname;
```

Notice that I also changed the query to use explicit, proper `join` syntax.  This is how you should be learning to write queries.