# Efficient SQLite3 Statement

Tags: database, sqlite

I wish to use the result of a query inside another query of SQLite3. For example, consider the following table in SQLite database.

```
No   Name   Value1  Value2  Value3  Salary
------------------------------------------
1   Kid1     100     0       0       300
2   Kid2     200     700     0       400
```

The above table may be created using the following code. Many Thanks to Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall for sharing this code.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  no integer primary key,
  name varchar(15) not null,
  value1 integer not null,
  value2 integer not null,
  value3 integer not null,
  salary decimal(13, 2) not null
);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(1,'Kid1',100,0,0,300);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(2,'Kid2',200,700,0,400);
```

Now, I need to update the SQLite3 table using the following rule.

For each row, update `Salary = Salary + Value1/N`, where N denotes the number of zero values in (Value2 and Value 3) in the row.

In the above example, after executing the command I would like to get the following table

```
No   Name   Value1  Value2  Value3  Salary
------------------------------------------
1   Kid1     100     0       0       350  
2   Kid2     200     700     0       600
```

Comment: Is this answer helpful to you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897811/sql-sql-lite-counting-records-after-filtering

Comment: *Where N denotes the number of `non-zero` values in (Value2 and Value 3) in the row.*

`Non-zero` or `zero` ? According to your resulting table it should be `zero`...!

Answer (score 1):

Paste CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements into your question to get more answers.  A lot of people won't take the time to reverse-engineer your database structure. (For SQLite, use `.dump your-table-name`.)

To answer your question, I think it's important to learn how to do this. I also think it's important not to do it. See the text and code below the horizontal rule below.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  no integer primary key,
  name varchar(15) not null,
  value1 integer not null,
  value2 integer not null,
  value3 integer not null,
  salary decimal(13, 2) not null
);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(1,'Kid1',100,0,0,300);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(2,'Kid2',200,700,0,400);
```

This SELECT statement gives us the number of zeroes in each row. We don't care which column (value2 or value3) the zero appears in.

```
select no, case when value2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end as num_zeroes from test
union all
select no, case when value3 = 0 then 1 else 0 end from test;
```

```
no          num_zeroes
----------  ----------
1           1         
2           0         
1           1         
2           1
```

The following statement sums up the count of zeroes for us.

```
select no, sum(num_zeroes) as num_zeroes
from (select no, case when value2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end as num_zeroes from test
      union all
      select no, case when value3 = 0 then 1 else 0 end from test) as zeroes
group by no;
```

```
no          num_zeroes
----------  ----------
1           2         
2           1
```

I think that result is useful enough to make a view out of it.

```
create view num_zeroes as 
select no, sum(num_zeroes) as num_zeroes
from (select no, case when value2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end as num_zeroes from test
      union all
      select no, case when value3 = 0 then 1 else 0 end from test) as zeroes
group by no;
```

Now we can do the calculation with a join and a little arithmetic. This SELECT statement shows how the pieces work.

```
select 
  t1.no, t1.value1, t1.salary, 
  t2.num_zeroes, t1.salary + (t1.value1/t2.num_zeroes) as new_salary
from test t1
inner join num_zeroes t2 on t1.no = t2.no;
```

This one does the update.

```
update test
set salary = (select t1.salary + (t1.value1/t2.num_zeroes) 
              from test t1 
              inner join num_zeroes t2 on t1.no = t2.no 
              where t1.no = test.no);
```

---

The problem with this kind of approach is that someone *might* run the update more than once. If that happens, it could be hard to recover the original values.

Create a table for salary history instead. Bad updates are easier to fix when you use a table of salary history.

I used the date '9999-12-31' to represent "the end of time".

```
pragma foreign_keys = on;

create table salary_history (
  no integer not null,
  start_date date not null,
  end_date date not null default '9999-12-31',
  salary decimal(13, 2) not null,
  foreign key (no) references test (no),
  primary key (no, start_date)
);
```

Insert a couple of rows to get us started. I pulled '2015-01-01' out of thin air. I don't know what value1, value2, and value3 mean in your original table, so I have no idea whether they should be moved into "salary_history". I left them alone.

```
insert into salary_history values
(1, '2015-01-01', '9999-12-31', 300),
(2, '2015-01-01', '9999-12-31', 400);
```

I think a view of the current salaries is generally a good idea, and it makes later calculations easier.

```
create view current_salary as
select no, start_date, end_date, salary
from salary_history
where current_date >= start_date 
  and current_date < end_date;
```

To update the salary history, wrap a transaction around two SQL UPDATE statements. The first one terminates current salaries by setting their end dates to the current date. The second one inserts a new row, which will become the current salary.

```
begin transaction;

update salary_history
set end_date = current_date
where end_date = '9999-12-31';

insert into salary_history
select 
  t1.no, current_date, '9999-12-31', 
  t1.salary + (t3.value1/t2.num_zeroes) as new_salary
from current_salary as t1
inner join num_zeroes as t2 on t1.no = t2.no
inner join test as t3 on t1.no = t3.no;

commit;
```